# Getting Response 500, on Skype for business android sample app

Tags: android, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I have meeting url which works on both the MAC desktop client and the web client, but when I use this url on the [skype for business sample app's GuessMeetingJoin](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-android-app-sdk-samples/tree/master/GuestMeetingJoin) app, I get a response 500 error, below is the stack trace. What I'd like to know is this a problem with the SDK or the server?

```
V/[Http] HttpConnection: get native -1186576384 httpCallback com.microsoft.office.lync.platform.http.HttpConnectionNativeCallback$1@1d713b
D/[Http] HttpConnection: Original URL: https://meet.lync.com/talviewo365/sanjoe/BEKD7GK8 method Get
D/[Http] HttpConnection: Decoded URL: https://meet.lync.com/talviewo365/sanjoe/BEKD7GK8
I/[Http] HttpConnection: Sending HTTP request: Get https://meet.lync.com/talviewo365/sanjoe/BEKD7GK8
D/[Http] HttpEngine: HttpEngine.execute called for Get https://meet.lync.com/talviewo365/sanjoe/BEKD7GK8
D/[Http] HttpEngine: AutoRedirect true for https://meet.lync.com/talviewo365/sanjoe/BEKD7GK8 and setting it to FALSE for manual handling
V/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Host name "meet.lync.com" converted to "meet.lync.com"
D/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Updating the host requested on this thread: host = meet.lync.com, threadId = 11977
D/[Http] HttpEngine: Executing request with Get https://meet.lync.com/talviewo365/sanjoe/BEKD7GK8 Connection pool count is  2
V/[Http] SfbSSLSocketFactory: Adding SNI Support for host meet.lync.com.
V/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Updating the last certificate checked for host. host = meet.lync.com, certificate = X509CertificateInfo { Issuer = Microsoft IT SSL SHA2, Subject = *.online.lync.com, SigAlgName = SHA256withRSA, NotBefore = 14 Mar 2015 05:13:17 a.m., NotAfter = 13 Mar 2017 05:13:17 a.m., SerialNumber = 2007067333650767853591306556382551138799503347 }, threadId = 11977
D/[Http] SfbCertificateTrustEngine: Certificate trusted by the standard OS trust manager: X509CertificateInfo { Issuer = Microsoft IT SSL SHA2, Subject = *.online.lync.com, SigAlgName = SHA256withRSA, NotBefore = 14 Mar 2015 05:13:17 a.m., NotAfter = 13 Mar 2017 05:13:17 a.m., SerialNumber = 2007067333650767853591306556382551138799503347 }
D/[Http] HttpEngine: Skipping further HTTP attempts that use serverCredentials, as they are null. This is normal for URLs that don't require HTTP authentication. Request: Get https://meet.lync.com/talviewo365/sanjoe/BEKD7GK8
V/[Http] HttpEngine: Handle redirection automatically - Received response of manually redirected request
D/[Http] HttpEngine: Recursive execute for redirection for request Get https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/Meet/?origurl=aHR0cHM6Ly9tZWV0Lmx5bmMuY29tL3RhbHZpZXdvMzY1L3NhbmpvZS9CRUtEN0dLOA!!
D/[Http] HttpEngine: HttpEngine.execute called for Get https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/Meet/?origurl=aHR0cHM6Ly9tZWV0Lmx5bmMuY29tL3RhbHZpZXdvMzY1L3NhbmpvZS9CRUtEN0dLOA!!
D/[Http] HttpEngine: AutoRedirect true for https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/Meet/?origurl=aHR0cHM6Ly9tZWV0Lmx5bmMuY29tL3RhbHZpZXdvMzY1L3NhbmpvZS9CRUtEN0dLOA!! and setting it to FALSE for manual handling
V/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Host name "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com" converted to "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com"
D/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Updating the host requested on this thread: host = webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com, threadId = 11977
D/[Http] HttpEngine: Executing request with Get https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/Meet/?origurl=aHR0cHM6Ly9tZWV0Lmx5bmMuY29tL3RhbHZpZXdvMzY1L3NhbmpvZS9CRUtEN0dLOA!! Connection pool count is  3
D/[Http] SfbCookieManager: Found 1 cookie headers to outgoing request to: https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/Meet/?origurl=aHR0cHM6Ly9tZWV0Lmx5bmMuY29tL3RhbHZpZXdvMzY1L3NhbmpvZS9CRUtEN0dLOA!!
V/[Http] SfbSSLSocketFactory: Adding SNI Support for host webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com.
V/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Updating the last certificate checked for host. host = webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com, certificate = X509CertificateInfo { Issuer = Microsoft IT SSL SHA2, Subject = *.online.lync.com, SigAlgName = SHA256withRSA, NotBefore = 14 Mar 2015 05:13:17 a.m., NotAfter = 13 Mar 2017 05:13:17 a.m., SerialNumber = 2007067333650767853591306556382551138799503347 }, threadId = 11977
D/[Http] SfbCertificateTrustEngine: Certificate trusted by the standard OS trust manager: X509CertificateInfo { Issuer = Microsoft IT SSL SHA2, Subject = *.online.lync.com, SigAlgName = SHA256withRSA, NotBefore = 14 Mar 2015 05:13:17 a.m., NotAfter = 13 Mar 2017 05:13:17 a.m., SerialNumber = 2007067333650767853591306556382551138799503347 }

                                                                                   --------- beginning of system
D/[Http] SfbCookieManager: Found 1 cookie headers to outgoing request to: https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/Meet/?origurl=aHR0cHM6Ly9tZWV0Lmx5bmMuY29tL3RhbHZpZXdvMzY1L3NhbmpvZS9CRUtEN0dLOA!!
D/[Http] HttpEngine: Skipping further HTTP attempts that use serverCredentials, as they are null. This is normal for URLs that don't require HTTP authentication. Request: Get https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/Meet/?origurl=aHR0cHM6Ly9tZWV0Lmx5bmMuY29tL3RhbHZpZXdvMzY1L3NhbmpvZS9CRUtEN0dLOA!!
V/[Http] HttpEngine: setting redirect uri to https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/Meet/?origurl=aHR0cHM6Ly9tZWV0Lmx5bmMuY29tL3RhbHZpZXdvMzY1L3NhbmpvZS9CRUtEN0dLOA!!
V/[Http] HttpConnection: ~~ Response headers 
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :cache-control Value :private
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :transfer-encoding Value :chunked
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :content-type Value :Application/vnd.microsoft.lync.meeting+xml; charset=utf-8
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-ms-server-fqdn Value :MAAIN102FES01.infra.lync.com
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-ms-correlation-id Value :2147491888
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :strict-transport-security Value :max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-content-type-options Value :nosniff
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :date Value :Tue, 18 Oct 2016 04:57:48 GMT
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :LastRedirectUrl Value :https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/Meet/?origurl=aHR0cHM6Ly9tZWV0Lmx5bmMuY29tL3RhbHZpZXdvMzY1L3NhbmpvZS9CRUtEN0dLOA!!
W/OkHttp: A connection to https://meet.lync.com/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
V/[Http] HttpCallback: onRecieveData
V/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Host name "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com" converted to "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com"
V/[Http] HttpCallback:  HttpCallback Finished successfully and statusCode 200
V/[Http] HttpCallback: mNativeObjectRef = -1186576384
D/NetworkTelemetry: network_request {Http_RequestMethod=Get, Http_Latency=1485 ms, Http_ServiceType=GenericRequest, Http_RequestTimeout=60, Http_ResponseCode=200, Http_RequestId=3, Http_RequestUri=https://meet.lync.com/talviewo365/sanjoe/BEKD7GK8, Http_ExceptionType=none}
I/[Http] HttpConnection: Got Response: 200 for: Get https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/Meet/?origurl=aHR0cHM6Ly9tZWV0Lmx5bmMuY29tL3RhbHZpZXdvMzY1L3NhbmpvZS9CRUtEN0dLOA!! 
V/[Http] HttpConnection: get native -1190709984 httpCallback com.microsoft.office.lync.platform.http.HttpConnectionNativeCallback$1@f19c546
D/[Http] HttpConnection: Original URL: https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications method Get
D/[Http] HttpConnection: Decoded URL: https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications
I/[Http] HttpConnection: Sending HTTP request: Get https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications
D/[Http] HttpEngine: HttpEngine.execute called for Get https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications
D/[Http] HttpEngine: AutoRedirect true for https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications and setting it to FALSE for manual handling
V/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Host name "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com" converted to "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com"
D/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Updating the host requested on this thread: host = webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com, threadId = 11967
D/[Http] HttpEngine: Executing request with Get https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications Connection pool count is  2
D/[Http] SfbCookieManager: Found 1 cookie headers to outgoing request to: https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications
D/[HttpAuth] CredentialsMap: URI "https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications" converted CredentialsMap key: "https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications"
D/[HttpAuth] SfbAuthenticator: Authentication STEP STARTED (with WWW-Authenticate) for HTTP response for https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications
D/[HttpAuth] SfbAuthenticator: Exception (SfbMissingAuthCredentialsException) caught while authenticating using (no challenge selected) scheme (for WWW-Authenticate) for response for https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications: com.microsoft.office.lync.platform.http.HttpProvider.OkHttpProvider.OkHttpAuthentication.exceptions.SfbMissingAuthCredentialsException: null credentials provided while authenticating header WWW-Authenticate for request https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications
D/MissingAuthCredentialsHelper: SfbMissingAuthCredentialsException received but not being tracked for:https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications
D/[Http] HttpEngine: Skipping further HTTP attempts that use serverCredentials, as they are null. This is normal for URLs that don't require HTTP authentication. Request: Get https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications
V/[Http] HttpConnection: ~~ Response headers 
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :content-type Value :text/html
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-ms-webticketurl Value :https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-ms-webticketsupported Value :cwt,saml
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-ms-server-fqdn Value :MAAIN102FES01.infra.lync.com
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-ms-correlation-id Value :2147491889
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :strict-transport-security Value :max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :date Value :Tue, 18 Oct 2016 04:57:48 GMT
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :content-length Value :1293
V/[Http] HttpCallback: onRecieveData
D/NetworkTelemetry: network_request {Http_RequestMethod=Get, Http_Latency=30 ms, Http_ServiceType=GenericRequest, Http_RequestTimeout=60, Http_ResponseCode=401, Http_RequestId=4, Http_RequestUri=https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications, Http_ExceptionType=none}
I/[Http] HttpConnection: Got Response: 401 for: Get https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/applications 
V/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Host name "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com" converted to "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com"
V/[Http] HttpCallback:  HttpCallback Finished successfully and statusCode 401
V/[Http] HttpCallback: mNativeObjectRef = -1190709984
V/[Http] HttpConnection: get native -1193264504 httpCallback com.microsoft.office.lync.platform.http.HttpConnectionNativeCallback$1@8661c34
D/[Http] HttpConnection: Original URL: https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex method Post
D/[Http] HttpConnection: Decoded URL: https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex
V/[Http] HttpConnection: set body- length=497
I/[Http] HttpConnection: Sending HTTP request: Post https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex
D/[Http] HttpEngine: HttpEngine.execute called for Post https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex
D/[Http] HttpEngine: AutoRedirect true for https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex and setting it to FALSE for manual handling
V/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Host name "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com" converted to "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com"
D/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Updating the host requested on this thread: host = webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com, threadId = 11972
D/[Http] HttpEngine: Executing request with Post https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex Connection pool count is  2
D/[Http] SfbCookieManager: Found 1 cookie headers to outgoing request to: https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex
D/[Http] HttpEngine: Skipping further HTTP attempts that use serverCredentials, as they are null. This is normal for URLs that don't require HTTP authentication. Request: Post https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex
V/[Http] HttpConnection: ~~ Response headers 
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :content-type Value :text/html
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-ms-diagnostics Value :28074;source="MAAIN102FES01.infra.lync.com";reason="Failed to lookup user domain"
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-ms-server-fqdn Value :MAAIN102FES01.infra.lync.com
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-ms-correlation-id Value :2147491890
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :strict-transport-security Value :max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-content-type-options Value :nosniff
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :date Value :Tue, 18 Oct 2016 04:57:48 GMT
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :content-length Value :1208
V/[Http] HttpCallback: onRecieveData
V/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Host name "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com" converted to "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com"
V/[Http] HttpCallback:  HttpCallback Finished successfully and statusCode 500
V/[Http] HttpCallback: mNativeObjectRef = -1193264504
D/NetworkTelemetry: network_request {Http_RequestMethod=Post, Http_Latency=68 ms, Http_ServiceType=GenericRequest, Http_RequestTimeout=60, Http_ResponseCode=500, Http_RequestId=5, Http_RequestUri=https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex, Http_ExceptionType=none}
I/[Http] HttpConnection: Got Response: 500 for: Post https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex 
D/SignInTelemetry: ui_http_cancel_all_requests {SignInCorrelationId=f08068df-7446-4557-8ba2-a0f0a537b608}
I/[Http] SfbCertificateTrustEngine: SfbCertificateTrustEngine is stopping.
D/[Http] SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager: SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager is stopping.
I/[Http] HttpEngine: Canceled all active requests.
I/[Http] SfbCertificateTrustEngine: SfbCertificateTrustEngine is starting.
D/[Http] SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager: SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager is starting.
D/SignInTelemetry: ui_http_cancel_all_requests {SignInCorrelationId=f08068df-7446-4557-8ba2-a0f0a537b608}
I/[Http] SfbCertificateTrustEngine: SfbCertificateTrustEngine is stopping.
D/[Http] SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager: SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager is stopping.
I/[Http] HttpEngine: Canceled all active requests.
I/[Http] SfbCertificateTrustEngine: SfbCertificateTrustEngine is starting.
D/[Http] SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager: SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager is starting.
D/SignInTelemetry: ui_http_cancel_all_requests {SignInCorrelationId=f08068df-7446-4557-8ba2-a0f0a537b608}
I/[Http] SfbCertificateTrustEngine: SfbCertificateTrustEngine is stopping.
D/[Http] SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager: SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager is stopping.
I/[Http] HttpEngine: Canceled all active requests.
I/[Http] SfbCertificateTrustEngine: SfbCertificateTrustEngine is starting.
D/[Http] SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager: SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager is starting.
V/[Http] HttpConnection: get native -1187398192 httpCallback com.microsoft.office.lync.platform.http.HttpConnectionNativeCallback$1@e62c7a0
D/[Http] HttpConnection: Original URL: https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex method Post
D/[Http] HttpConnection: Decoded URL: https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex
V/[Http] HttpConnection: set body- length=497
I/[Http] HttpConnection: Sending HTTP request: Post https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex
D/[Http] HttpEngine: HttpEngine.execute called for Post https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex
D/[Http] HttpEngine: AutoRedirect true for https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex and setting it to FALSE for manual handling
V/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Host name "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com" converted to "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com"
D/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Updating the host requested on this thread: host = webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com, threadId = 11974
D/[Http] HttpEngine: Executing request with Post https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex Connection pool count is  2
V/[Http] SfbSSLSocketFactory: Adding SNI Support for host webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com.
V/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Updating the last certificate checked for host. host = webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com, certificate = X509CertificateInfo { Issuer = Microsoft IT SSL SHA2, Subject = *.online.lync.com, SigAlgName = SHA256withRSA, NotBefore = 14 Mar 2015 05:13:17 a.m., NotAfter = 13 Mar 2017 05:13:17 a.m., SerialNumber = 2007067333650767853591306556382551138799503347 }, threadId = 11974
D/[Http] SfbCertificateTrustEngine: Certificate trusted by the standard OS trust manager: X509CertificateInfo { Issuer = Microsoft IT SSL SHA2, Subject = *.online.lync.com, SigAlgName = SHA256withRSA, NotBefore = 14 Mar 2015 05:13:17 a.m., NotAfter = 13 Mar 2017 05:13:17 a.m., SerialNumber = 2007067333650767853591306556382551138799503347 }
D/SignInTelemetry: ui_http_cancel_all_requests {SignInCorrelationId=f08068df-7446-4557-8ba2-a0f0a537b608}
I/[Http] SfbCertificateTrustEngine: SfbCertificateTrustEngine is stopping.
D/[Http] SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager: SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager is stopping.
D/[Http] HttpEngine: Canceling request Post https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex
I/[Http] SfbOkHttpRequest: Canceling Request because of: HttpEngine.cancelActiveRequests(): Post https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex
I/[Http] HttpEngine: Canceled all active requests.
I/[Http] SfbCertificateTrustEngine: SfbCertificateTrustEngine is starting.
D/[Http] SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager: SfbUserCertificateApprovalManager is starting.
D/[Http] SfbCookieManager: Found 1 cookie headers to outgoing request to: https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex
D/[Http] HttpEngine: Skipping further HTTP attempts that use serverCredentials, as they are null. This is normal for URLs that don't require HTTP authentication. Request: Post https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex
V/[Http] HttpConnection: ~~ Response headers 
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :content-type Value :text/html
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-ms-diagnostics Value :28074;source="MAAIN102FES03.infra.lync.com";reason="Failed to lookup user domain"
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-ms-server-fqdn Value :MAAIN102FES03.infra.lync.com
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-ms-correlation-id Value :2147487545
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :strict-transport-security Value :max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :x-content-type-options Value :nosniff
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :date Value :Tue, 18 Oct 2016 04:58:57 GMT
V/[Http] HttpConnection:  Header :content-length Value :1208
V/[Http] HttpCallback: onRecieveData
V/[Http] ThreadHostCertificateMapper: Host name "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com" converted to "webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com"
D/NetworkTelemetry: network_request {Http_RequestMethod=Post, Http_Latency=3546 ms, Http_ServiceType=GenericRequest, Http_RequestTimeout=60, Http_ResponseCode=500, Http_RequestId=6, Http_RequestUri=https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex, Http_ExceptionType=none}
I/[Http] HttpConnection: Got Response: 500 for: Post https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/WebTicket/WebTicketService.svc/mex 
V/[Http] HttpCallback:  HttpCallback Finished successfully and statusCode 500
V/[Http] HttpCallback: mNativeObjectRef = -1187398192
```

Comment: I believe you know error code 500 means that the problem is on the server side :)

Comment: @SripadRaj yes i understand that but i'd like to know if its because I hadn't set up the meeting correctly or is it something else is all.

Comment: Looks like a temporary server failure. Does it persist yet? Any misconfiguration would result in 4xx status.